# Start a new github project based on another project's branch

Tags: git, github

I started a github project with another colleague to improve an app made by him. He hosted it in his github page and allowed me to push changes.

I made changes to the master branch, but after some time I decided to add a new branch “myversion” because I needed to make significant changes to the original idea and wanted to preserve the original idea.

I continued making changes to myversion brach and now I’ve came to a situation that all myversion is a completely different project from master and all the code is mine except for the original push from my colleague.

What I want to do is to continue the work in my own github account, making the “myversion” branch the “master” branch of my new project and leaving my colleague’s github with the master (original) version.

I don’t want to fork it since it does not make any sense to keep pushing changes to the original project since now they are different projects.

And finally, I’d like to keep the commit history of the project to know what changes I’ve made until today.

I am not sure of what’s the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a new remote or change the remote `origin`.

```
git remote set-url origin <path_to_new_repo>

git checkout master
git merge myversion
git push origin master
```

If you want to discard the code in master branch altogether,

```
git checkout myversion
git branch -d master
git branch -m master
git push origin master
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. It only requires a git pull origin before pushing changes in order to update files from the new remote repository (in my case, i added a new readme file).

Comment: worked for me as well. Thanks!!!